# Disable scroll on thum list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am creating a slider based on [master slider](http://www.masterslider.com/wordpress/free/templates/slider-with-vertical-thumbnails/) I want to remove scroll event on thumb-list so that user can not scroll thumb list .I checked all the option in admin site but not working and no option for stop thumb scroll.I also tried jquery but not succeed any help should be appreciated I want to stop scroll only on the thumb list not whole body.

```
   function preventDefault(e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          if (e.preventDefault)
              e.preventDefault();
          e.returnValue = false;  
        }

        function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
            if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
                preventDefault(e);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function disableScroll() {
          if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
              window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
          window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
          window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
          window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
          document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
        }
disableScroll();
```

Comment: in ms-thumbs-cont class, change transform to transform:none !important; If it works for you then let me know so i can post as answer or can give you other suggestion.

Comment: It is working but next thumb is not coming after 3 thumb after click

Comment: did not get you? you want those thumb img after clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css it will block scrolling

```
 body, html { 
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but  I want to stop scroll only on the thumb list not whole body.

Comment: @user3514011, please check my comment. Thanx